# "TO" vs "AND" in this context

Tags: sentence-choice

I use the following two sentences alternatively:

> 1. I reached there **and** found out she was dead.

> 2. I reached there **to** find out she was dead.

Can I consider them to be carrying the **same meaning?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

They do have very similar meanings. Note that you cannot say "I reached there". You need a specific goal after 'reached':

- I reached the mountain
- I reached the hotel
- I reached the finish line

Also, you often see "only to" instead of just "to", as in your second example:

- I reached the hotel, **only** to find she was dead

The slightly different meaning becomes clearer now. The version with 'and' presents a simple sequence of events, whereas the version with '[only] to' focuses more on the thwarted expectations of the narrator.

Comment: The "specific goal" which "reach" requires can still be a placeholder, but that placeholder is **it**, not _there_: "Once I reached **it**, ..." and in this case "it" must refer to a previously specified or understood goal.

Comment: @TypeIA true. My explanation was hasty.